# Java Springboot Unit-Testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, crud

Building a UnitTest into a CRUD Application

I tried adding a hardcoded business item as variables to the Application.[Unit Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSL3A.png)[Component class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOU6Q.png) [Controller Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F0wB.png)[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5xc6.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Check this link https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2019/10/spring-boot-integration-tests-to-dao-or.html?m=1

Comment: I see I omitted the 
        when(itemBusinessService.retrieveHardcodedItem()).thenReturn(new Item(1, "Sugar2", 10, 100));